# Finding Descendents in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have this problem with my C# API that I unfortunately posted incorrectly & got partially incorrect answers, so I'm going to try again since I've still not solved it (trying for hours)

Here's my XML file :

```
<CHandlingDataMgr>
    <HandlingData>
        <Item type="CHandlingData">
            <handlingName>Plane</handlingName>
            <fMass value="140000.000000" />
            <SubHandlingData>
                <Item type="CFlyingHandlingData">
                    <handlingType>HANDLING_TYPE_FLYING</handlingType>
                    <fThrust value="0.630000" />
            </SubHandlingData>
 </Item>
        </Item>
```

Please note: SubHandlingData is in a separate sub-section within the same item, a 2nd item type is called.

Here's the C# Code :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var items = doc.Descendants("HandlingData").Elements("Item");
    var query = from i in items
                select new
                {
                    HandlingName = (string)i.Element("handlingName"),                             (decimal?)i.Element("fThrust").Attribute("value"),
                    HandlingType = (string)i.Element("handlingType")
                };

    StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        var k = item.dunno;
        test.Append(k);
        richTextBox1.Text = test.ToString();
    }
}
```

The above code works fine, but doesn't work with SubHandlingData. This means such values as HandlingType is not seen, I've added the element for this & it returns errors, have also tried including multiple decedents which then doesn't find HandlingName, or HandlingType. I want my output to be if handlingType == "HANDLING_TYPE_FLYING", richtextbox1.text = this.HandlingName. I hope I have explained this clearly enough to gain an answer as this has troubled me for a while.

My Problem in short: Program does not find any SubHandlingData inside my XML document.

Question in short: How to find `<SubHandlingData>` inside `<item>`  (how to find sub-section of code inside same item)

Comment: Your xml is malformed (some elements are not closed). Please fix it to make your problem clear.

Comment: This is a section of the code, missing button_click & open/close parenthesis for it, will edit now. -Thanks

Comment: Would it kill you to put some sane indentation in your code and data?...

Comment: Your XML is still wrong. Try to align it properly, and you'll see.

Comment: I have edited it slightly, but it's as close to original as can get without taking up a massive code box. Legit - Can't be more clear

Comment: If someone could actually just drop any answer regarding this, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: @DannyNichols - We're here to help, but you shouldn't make our job to help you any harder than it needs to be. If you're asked to fix the XML then you should fix the XML.

Comment: The XML is part of a much bigger project, I could not edit it without causing mass of other problems. Posting here was a last resort & I did try my best to make it clear. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From @Matthew's edit, you can see there is `<Item>` not closed within `<SubHandlingData>`. If your actual XML has such structure then it won't get parsed successfully to `XDocument`. But if your actual XML has it closed, about like so I assume :

```
<HandlingData>
   <Item type="CHandlingData">
      <handlingName>Plane</handlingName>
      <fMass value="140000.000000" />
      <SubHandlingData>
         <Item type="CFlyingHandlingData">
            <handlingType>HANDLING_TYPE_FLYING</handlingType>
            <fThrust value="0.630000" />
         </Item>
      </SubHandlingData>
   </Item>
</HandlingData>
```

... then we can continue. You can try to follow path from outer `Item` to `handlingType` which is : SubHandlingData > Item > handlingType, to get handlingType data from current outer item :

```
var query = from i in items
            select new
            {
               HandlingName = (string)i.Element("handlingName"),
               HandlingType = (string)i.Element("SubHandlingData")
                                       .Element("Item")
                                       .Element("handlingType")
            };
```

Comment: +1, but I also think it's noteworthy that this assumes the presence of exactly one `Item` under the `SubHandlingData` element. That's not something that's addressed in the question, of course, but it looks like a weird schema if there's only ever one child.

Comment: I have just looked over the XML once more & you're both right @MatthewHaugen @ har07 , sorry for not reading/printing it properly & thanks for making the assumption & providing correct solution